# I am doing a voice Assistant with python and got an error can you help me with this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, voice, pyaudio, google-voice-actions

```
# Import packages
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
from gtts import gTTS
import datetime
import warnings
import calendar
import random
import wikipedia

# Ignore any warning messages
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


# Record audio and return as string
def recordAudio():
    # record the audio
    r = sr.Recognizer()  # creating a speech recogniser

    # open the mic and start recording
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Say Something:')
        audio = r.listen(source)
    # Use google speech recognition
    data = ''
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said : ' + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print('Google Speech recognition not undstand you, unknown error')
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print('Request results from google speechrecognition service error' + e)

    return data


recordAudio()


# A fuction to get the virtual assistant response
def assistantResponse(text):
    print(text)

    # convert the text to speech
    myobj = gTTS(text=text, lang='en', slow=False)

    # save the audio to a file
    myobj.save('assistant_response.mp3')

    # SPlay the converted file
    os.system('start assistant_response.mp3')


# A function for wake word
def wakeWord(text):
    WAKE_WORDS = {'hey bongo', 'hey man', 'hey computer', 'okay google'}  # list of wake words

    text = text.lower()  # convert the text to lower case words

    # Check to see if user input is a wake eord
    for phrase in WAKE_WORDS:
        if phrase in text:
            return True

    # If The wake word is not found in text from the loop , soo it returns False
    return False


# A function to get the current date
def getDate():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    my_date = datetime.datetime.today()
    weekday = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]  # sunday
    monthNum = now.month
    dayNum = now.day

    # A list of months
    month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', ' April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', ' October',
                   'November', 'December']

    # A list of ordinal Numbers
    ordinalNumbers = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', ' 4th', '5th', '6th', '7th', '8th', '9th', '10th', '11th', '12th', '13th',
                      '14th', '15th', '16th',
                      '17th', '18th', '19th', '20th', '21st', '22nd', '23rd', '24rd', '25th', '26th', '27th', '28th',
                      '29th', '30th', '31st']

    return 'Today is ' + weekday + ' ' + month_names[monthNum - 1] + ' the ' + ordinalNumbers[dayNum - 1] + ' .'


# Fuction to return greeting
def greeting(text):
    # Greeting inputs
    GREETING_INPUTS = ['hi', 'hey', 'hola', 'wassup', 'hello']

    # Greeting response
    GREETING_RESPONSES = ['howdy', 'all that good', 'hello master', 'heythere']

    # If users input is a greeting, then return a randomly chosen greetng response
    for word in text.split():
        if word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
            return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES) + '.'

    # If no greeting was detected
    return ''


# A functions to get persons name from text
def getPerson(text):
    wordList = text.split()  # splits the text to words

    for i in range(0, len(wordList)):
        if i + 3 <= len(wordList) - 1 and wordList[i].lower() == 'who' and wordList[i + 1].lower() == 'is':
            return wordList[i + 2] + ' ' + wordList[i + 3]


while True:

    # record the audio
    text = recordAudio()
    response = ''

    # check for the wake word / phrase
    if (wakeWord(text) == True):

        # check for greetings by the user
        response = response + greeting(text)

        # check to see if the user has said anything about data
        if ('date' in text):
            get_date = getDate()
            response = response + ' ' + get_date

        # check to see if the user said 'who is'
        if ('who is' in text):
            person = getPerson(text)
            wiki = wikipedia.summary(person, sentences=2)
            response = response + ' ' + wiki

        # assistant respond back using audio and text from response
        assistantResponse(response)
```

*below is the error*

```
C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\YazılımBilimi\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/90551/PycharmProjects/YazılımBilimi/voiceassistan.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\YazılımBilimi\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/90551/PycharmProjects/YazılımBilimi/voiceassistan.py", line 37, in <module>
    recordAudio()
  File "C:/Users/90551/PycharmProjects/YazılımBilimi/voiceassistan.py", line 21, in recordAudio
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\YazılımBilimi\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\90551\PycharmProjects\YazılımBilimi\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I installed PyAudio after it says "Download PyAudio" but it still says download PyAudio.
**What module or packages should I download more??.**
I do not debug it ı only installed PyAudio.
**This is all of the information that I know.**
**İf I will try to give more information if you can't figure out how to solve it:).**
**Thanks all Stackoverflow community for help.**

Comment: Please don't expect others to be "quick", your urgency is not theirs.

Comment: ok ı just write it for information stackoverflow was saying "youre full of code please add some information" and ı add a sentence like this actually you there is nothing like this ı got plenty of time

Answer (score 0):

sorry I didn't do this sooner, but start with copy and pasting this into terminal

```
pip install PyAudio
```

if this doesn't work don't worry it happened to me aswell,
you will have to download home-brew as this allows us to download portaudio, copy and paste this into terminal.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

this will download Homebrew.

Once this is downloaded then copy and paste this into terminal

```
brew install portaudio
```

portaudio allows us to download pyaudio.

then try installing the package pyaudio through pycharm or whatever coding program you use.

Comment: You're assuming the OP is on Mac. Is that a safe assumption?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install `PyAudio` using `pip`, you might get an error, so try to install it using `pipwin`
Install `pipwin` by,

```
pip install pipwin
```

Then install `PyAudio` by,

```
pipwin install PyAudio
```